# nginx not letting me change the web root

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server, tomcat, docker

Even though I change the `root` directive to point to `/var/www/html`, nginx is attempting to load files out of `/var/www` as my root directory.

I have restarted nginx and received "OK" after changing default.conf.

Am I doing something wrong? Worth nothing, this nginx server is running inside a docker container.

==================================

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile off;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log ;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##


        gzip on;


        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
        ##

        #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

        ##
        # nginx-passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
        ##

        #passenger_root /usr;
        #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    index  index.cfm index.html index.htm;
    root   /var/www/html;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    set $path_info $request_uri;

    try_files $uri /index.cfm?$args;

    location ~* \.(cfm|cfc|cfr)$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header XAJP-PATH-INFO $path_info;
        proxy_connect_timeout 600;
        proxy_send_timeout 600;
        proxy_read_timeout 600;
        send_timeout 600;
    }

}
```

[image: nginx root not correct]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured nginx to use this `root` path for your website. This applies to static resources served by nginx.

However, your application server doesn't use nginx `root` option, since it is independent from nginx.

You need to fix your application server configuration.

Comment: Score! In my case, I needed to edit the Tomcat config `/usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml` to change the `docBase` reference to `/var/www/html`. Thanks Tero!